# Commands not running on Linux EC2 instance launch

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, startup

I've got a AWS EC2 Linux instance where the user data has been set as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum group mark install -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support"
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
groupadd www
usermod -a -G www ec2-user
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R root:www /var/www
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
```

The desired goal is to get the apache page when the instance is called through the load balancer, but when the instance starts up, I get a 502 bad gateway status code, I then ssh into the instance run the commands manually and I get the apache page as expected.

I'm following the [linkedlearning aws essential training](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/amazon-web-services-essential-training-2) 
, followed the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), I've also added a index.php to /var/www/html.
I get the expected result when running the commands manually but not when using the instance settings user data, what am I doing wrong or missing?

Many thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Can you paste an output of your `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` from the instance? That should log any errors in the launch process.

Comment: Are you using the `Amazon Linux 2` or `Amazon Linux` AMI?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Amazon Linux

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @jww, I can move this question there if necessary. Does scripting not fall under development?

Comment: ALWAYS use FULL paths and you'll avoid a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your User Data on an instance and the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file contained:

```
Marked install: Web Server,MySQL Database,PHP Support
httpd: unrecognized service
error reading information on service httpd: No such file or directory
usermod: group 'apache' does not exist
chown: cannot access ‘/var/www’: No such file or directory
chown: invalid group: ‘ec2-user:apache’
chmod: cannot access ‘/var/www’: No such file or directory
find: `/var/www': No such file or directory
find: `/var/www': No such file or directory
Aug 18 06:38:38 cloud-init[2638]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Aug 18 06:38:38 cloud-init[2638]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Aug 18 06:38:38 cloud-init[2638]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Sat, 18 Aug 2018 06:38:38 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 16.54 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein, the instance where this user data was added was created from a AMI which has httpd already installed. I'm going to try adding the http install command to the user data as well thanks John.